# How to use user input token in Checkbox value in Splunk Dashboard?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am on Splunk 8.1 trying to create a dynamic dashboard. I am trying to create a `multisearch` query, the searches for which will be based on the checkboxes that the user clicks.

```
<input type="time" token="field1">
    <label>Time</label>
    <default>
        <earliest>-15m</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
    </default>
</input>
<input type="text" token="userinput1">
    <label>User Input 1</label>
</input>
<input type="text" token="userinput2">
    <label>User Input 2</label>
</input>
<input type="checkbox" token="indexesSelected" searchWhenChanged="true">
    <label>Indexes</label>
    <choice value="[search index=index1 $userinput1$ $userinput2$]">Index 1</choice>
    <choice value="[search index=index2 $userinput1$ $userinput2$]">Index 2</choice>
    <default></default>
    <initialValue></initialValue>
    <delimiter> </delimiter>
    <prefix>| multisearch [eval test1="test1"] [eval test2="test2"] </prefix>
</input>
```

The search part looks like this:

```
<search>
    <query>$indexesSelected$ 
        | table _time, index, field1, field2, field3, field4 
        | sort Time
    </query>
    <earliest>$field1.earliest$</earliest>
    <latest>$field1.latest$</latest>
</search>
```

This works as expected except that the final query looks like this:

```
| multisearch [eval test1="test1"] [eval test2="test2"]
[search index=index1 $userinput1$ $userinput2$]
[search index=index2 $userinput1$ $userinput2$]
```

How can I make these **`$userinput1$`** and **`$userinput2$`** be converted to their token value from the user inputs in the dashboard and not as literal strings.

I have tried to use `<change>` tags to use `eval` and `set` based on the `<condition>` that the user selects, but `eval` does not allow token value and replaces with literal strings only. Something like this:

```
<change>
    <condition match="like($indexesSelected$,&quot;%index1%&quot;)">
        <eval token="finalQuery">replace($indexesSelected$,"index1", "[search index=index1 $userinput1$ $userinput2$]")</eval>
    </condition>
    <condition match="like($indexesSelected$,&quot;%index2%&quot;)">
        <eval token="finalQuery">replace($indexesSelected$,"index2", "[search index=index2 $userinput1$ $userinput2$]")</eval>
    </condition>
</change>
```